# Is the auto generated photologue image urls overridable?

Tags: django, photologue, media-url

I have two separate servers. One is hosting django instance on `"www.example.com"`, the other is serving static files on `"static.example.com"`. In django settings, `MEDIA_URL` points to `"static.example.com"`. Therefore my photologue is using the `"static.example.com"` domain.

I want to use `"www.example.com"` for my photologue, but I can't figure out how I can override the `MEDIA_URL` setting for the photologue. Do you know any way to solve this?

**Note:** Django is serving over apache, Static files hosted on AWS (Amazon Web Service). I just want to change only photologue domain. Other static files must stay where they are.

Comment: Try to serve media file via web servers like apache...

Comment: I don't get what you exactly mean. Can you tell more descriptive?

Comment: We genrally serve static contents like images via apache and not via django

Comment: I added a note for that into my question :) I was served static files with apache where django living. Afterwards I moved static files to Amazon AWS for reducing traffic on project server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Photologue doesn't provide a setting for this.

But looking at the code I found a workaround that should do the trick. I assume you use the `get_SIZE_url()` methods. All of those methods call `self.cache_url()`. So, you could create a subclass of `ImageModel` (or `Photo` if you want to have the functionality that comes with it) which overrides this method.

```
from photologue.models import ImageModel  # or Photo

class LocalPhoto(ImageModel):   # or Photo

    def cache_url(self):
        local_path = os.path.dirname(self.image.url)[7:].split('/', 1)[1]
        return '/%s/%s' % (local_path, 'cache')
```

If you extended `Photo` you already have a working `get_absolute_url()` otherwise an implementation is straight forward.

Django admin uses `get_admin_thumbnail_url()` so if you define a `PhotoSize` with name 'admin_thumbnail' the above method should work there too.

Effects have a method `sample_url()` used to show the effect on a sample image in Django admin. This method is based on `MEDIA_URL` so it won't work. Unfortunately in this case you cannot simply override this method. But since these images won't change you could upload them to AWS.